# Firefox: No click events while JavaScript is running

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, event-handling

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
  function wait() {
    // I know this is obsolete
    var ms = 3000 + new Date().getTime();
    while(ms > new Date()) {}
    console.log("3 Seconds Are Over");
  }

  function clickHandler() {
    console.log("Click");
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

  wait();
  console.log("End Global Execution Context");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As the `EventHandler` is registered before JavaScript waits 3 seconds, it should log `"Click"` at the end, even when I click within these 3 seconds.

However it only logs `"Click"` when I click **after** `"End Global Execution Context"`.

Comment: JS is by default single threaded. Depending on what context you're running this, you can use something like web workers or child processes to parallelize this.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Yes, the event should be put on the queue, then fired after the loop; this is exactly what I am getting from your code. If you are not getting "Click" (after 3 seconds) when you click within the first 3 seconds, can you please note which browser you are testing with, as I cannot reproduce your findings?

Comment: @Amadan I use Firefox ESR 45.4.0 on debian

Comment: I don't have one of those handy; so just to make it explicit, [this](http://jsbin.com/xinudojazo/edit?html,js,output) does what I said for me (Chrome on OS X) - regardless of when you click in "Output" window, it will log "click" (except delayed, if click happens within the first 3 seconds of loading, or clicking "Run").

Comment: "it should log "Click" at the end" why do you think that? Event dispatch is async, it doesn't give you a guarantee it of exact delivery between executing some statement or another.

Comment: @Amadan when I run that script on JS Bin, it works fine, however when I run it locally, it doesn't - this is odd

Comment: @pvg: It can't fire the event during the loop; it should fire it at the first opportunity after the current task has terminated, unless there were some events pushed to the stack before it, in which case it should fire immediately after those are completed. JS "async" is deterministic. However, what shouldn't happen is for the event not to fire at all, which OP is reporting.

Comment: @Amadan ah I read it as 'click is logged after log of "end whatever"'

Comment: Tested on local (still Chrome/OSX). It will not emit "click" if I click too soon (i.e. the script has not yet had time to load), which is expected (but only once, because after that it is cached and will load faster than I can click).

Comment: @Amadan I just discovered something strange: when I log "Waiting..." for instance right before I invoke wait, it loads three seconds, then logs "Waiting..." and the immediately logs "End ..."

Comment: same, when I log something before addEventListener

Comment: Now that is not strange at all. There is only one thread per tab (excluding Web workers), that is shared by JavaScript and UI updates. Thus, if you log something during your JavaScript task, the log doesn't get painted until the task is finished. Try adding an animated GIF, and you will see that even the animation stops entirely while your JS task is running.

Comment: @Amadan I don't understand. Isn't it supposed to log before it waits, as wait is invoked after log is invoked?

Comment: It should in theory log before it waits. And it does in typical browsers. This is grasping a little but you should set the charset to utf8, and make sure your local file has no weird characters in it, potentially by starting a new one and cutting and pasting what you posted here. Also, double check against another browser.

Comment: @Amadan However it doesn't handle click events

Comment: @Amadan I can't find a single current browser that actually does that. So it is fairly odd. The console repaint is independent of js anyway so it would be pretty odd to see no updates just because something ate up the js thread.

Comment: @pvg: Hmm, seems you're right. Weird, could have sworn console was painted in JS thread.

Comment: Try this https://rawgit.com/pvg/test/master/tt.html   if it's still broken, your browser is broken.

Comment: @pvg yep, same behavior

Comment: Yeah I think you should at a minimum try another browser. Another big difference is you're running X11 and we're putzing around on macs but it's hard to imagine events just getting thrown away.

Comment: Okay, I'll install a new browser on occasion. Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my installation was corrupt. A new installation fixed the problem.